# Intel Graphics: stock driver vs modesetting driver vs Intel download

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, intel-graphics, intel

I've just removed xserver-xorg-video-intel due to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1573959). This means I've fallen back to the modesetting driver, which Debian [now recommends](https://packages.debian.org/sid/xserver-xorg-video-intel). Can any provide a comparison of the relative merits of the stock xorg Intel driver, vs the modesetting driver, vs the one you can [download from Intel](https://01.org/linuxgraphics)?

I'm running a Haswell (mobile) chipset, on 16.04, but am interest in a general response.

Comment: Did you get any useful information on that? Can you please share? I also have the same dillema!

Comment: Sorry, have stopped using Ubuntu for now and can't remember what I settled for at the time!

Answer (score 4):

Intel still performs better as you can see here:
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-DDX-May-Tests

OTOH, there are a lot of discussion about the slow development in the Intel driver:
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4cojj9/it_is_probably_time_to_ditch_xf86videointel/

To make it complete, the last open source developer in Intel is out:
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Kristian-Hosgberg-Departs-Intel

Modesetting is what you will use whenever you mix more than one card.  E.g. NVidia cards.  With output sinks on xrandr.